# Solr - Indexing products with attributes as Key / Value pair

Tags: solr

I’m currently looking at developing a solr application to index products on our e-commerce website.

Some example fields in the schema are:

- ProductID
- ProductName
- Description
- Price
- Categories (multi-value)
- *Attributes*

Attributes are a list of key-value pairs. 
For example:

Type = Rose
Position = Full Sun
Position = Shade
Colour = Red

I am going to store the fields, so that my pages can be generated from a search result.

How is it best to represent these?

I was thinking of maybe having some dynamic fields for indexing:
attribute_* for example (attribute_position)
And then “attribute” for stored value (For returning, for displaying) - storing multiple  fields
The value of an “attribute” field could be (for example) Position|Full Sun - then let the client handle the displaying?

Are there any better ways of doing this?

As a footnote- I will be using Solrnet as a client for querying (probably not relevant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would not recommend storing your entire document in your search engine. The only thing you should store in Solr is those things that you wish to search on. Yes, it supports storing more, however, taking advantage of this can cause issues down the road with index size, master/slave replication time, etc. Ideally, the only thing in Solr is things you wish to search/sort on and a document ID that is unique enough to fetch document data with from another source that is optimized for storing .... documents.

However, if you decide to ignore this advice, then you can easily store your name value pairs in a single field. If your name value pairs have a limited character set, you can easily concatenate the name value pairs into a single string. Then, parse them on the way out when you are forming your web page for display. There's no need to come up with a more complex schema to support this. Multiple fields for storing these will only increase your index overhead, which buys you nothing.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not "sensible" to store data for retrieval as well as index it, however we will have (at most) 8000 documents (probably around half of this) all fairly small - even the raw CSV of this data is well under 100mb

Would this method of concatenating the string allow searching?
For example, selecting products where Colour = Red?

Comment: No, it wouldn't work well for that. I only thought you wanted to store this name/value pair data for the document display purposes, not for indexing. I misunderstood. In that case, you may want to use dynamic fields for the searching side of things, and then store the string as I suggested for reconstituting the document for display. It's often better to separate the search and display concerns by storing them separately, even if it's in the search index.